# How to make separate log file for error, warning in python?

Tags: python, logging

I want to make a separate log for errors, warning, and combined log for errors and warning in python. If I used python own logging mechanism to make log, I only can have one log file which can have errors, warning. I want to be more specific for that, I want to make a separate log only for errors, only for warnings, and combined log for errors and warning. I came across some logging function but I still can't make separate log files that what I expected. How can I fetch the errors, warning, and make separate log files for them? Is there any way of doing this? any possible thoughts? can anyone put me a possible approach to make this happen?

**my current attempt**:

here is what I tried so far, and I couldn't make a separate log for errors and warning, I mean warning message from python terminal didn't make log still.

```
import logging

def getLogger(LOG_NAME = '', LOG_FILE_INFO  = 'file.log', LOG_FILE_ERROR = 'file.err'):
    LOG_FORMAT = '%(asctime)s %(name)-12s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s'
    log = logging.getLogger(LOG_NAME)
    log_formatter = logging.Formatter(LOG_FORMAT)
    # comment this to suppress console output
    stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    stream_handler.setFormatter(log_formatter)
    log.addHandler(stream_handler)

    file_handler_info = logging.FileHandler(LOG_FILE_INFO, mode='w')
    file_handler_info.setFormatter(log_formatter)
    file_handler_info.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    log.addHandler(file_handler_info)

    file_handler_error = logging.FileHandler(LOG_FILE_ERROR, mode='w')
    file_handler_error.setFormatter(log_formatter)
    file_handler_error.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
    log.addHandler(file_handler_error)
    log.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    return log
```

**coding logic**

here is the coding logic in my python function where I am gonna use log function to make separate log with `ifelse` condition:

```
if val == "combined":
    print("printing out combined log info including error, warning")
elif val == "error":
     print("printing out error log info only")
else:
    print("print out rlog info from running R functions")
```

how do I make this implementation better? how do I achieve the task of making a separate log for errors, warning, and combined logs of errors and warnings? any better idea or thoughts? thanks

**update**:

this is app running session from python console, and I want to make log of this:

```
>  * Environment: production    WARNING: This is a development server.
> Do not use it in a production deployment.    Use a production WSGI
> server instead.  * Debug mode: off  * Running on http://0.0.0.0:8080/
> (Press CTRL+C to quit)
> 127.0.0.1 - - [20/May/2020 10:31:37] "[37mGET /api/v1/ui/ HTTP/1.1[0m" 200 -
> 127.0.0.1 - - [20/May/2020 10:31:38] "[37mGET /api/v1/openapi.json HTTP/1.1[0m" 200 - 2020-05-20
> 10:31:52,545-immunomatch_ed-INFO-getting ready to retrieve immunoMatch
> System version... 2020-05-20 10:31:52,547-immunomatch_ed-WARNING-This
> is a WARNING message 2020-05-20 10:31:52,548-immunomatch_ed-ERROR-This
> is an ERROR message
> 127.0.0.1 - - [20/May/2020 10:31:52] "[37mGET /api/v1/about HTTP/1.1[0m" 200 - 2020-05-20
> 10:32:18,288-immunomatch_ed-INFO-getting ready to retrieve immunoMatch
> score...
> 127.0.0.1 - - [20/May/2020 10:32:19] "[37mPOST /api/v1/immunomatch_ed HTTP/1.1[0m" 200 - 2020-05-20
> 10:40:49,746-immunomatch_ed-INFO-getting ready to retrieve R session
> info... 2020-05-20 10:40:49,746-immunomatch_ed-WARNING-This is a
> WARNING message 2020-05-20 10:40:49,749-immunomatch_ed-ERROR-This is
> an ERROR message
> C:\Users\sam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\connexion\apis\flask_api.py:199:
> FutureWarning: Implicit (flask) JSON serialization will change in the
> next major version. This is triggered because a response body is being
> serialized as JSON even though the mimetype is not a JSON type. This
> will be replaced by something that is mimetype-specific and may raise
> an error instead of silently converting everything to JSON. Please
> make sure to specify media/mime types in your specs.   FutureWarning 
> # a Deprecation targeted at application users.
> 127.0.0.1 - - [20/May/2020 10:40:50] "[37mGET /api/v1/rsession HTTP/1.1[0m" 200 - printing out combined log info including error,
> warning
> 127.0.0.1 - - [20/May/2020 10:41:38] "[37mGET /api/v1/log?type=combined HTTP/1.1[0m" 200 -
```

but above log function that I coded is not getting those to log file. How can I make a log of this? any idea?

Comment: Won't this make it impossible to follow a single "event" in your application?

Comment: @jordanm in my flask app, I want to catch error, warnings, and make separate logs, but I didn't have luck what I expected for. Would you mind to share your possible thought if you have? I was thinking of using `subprocess` to catch errors, warning from os-related log message, but I am not sure.

Comment: @jordanm do you have possible thought how do we deal with single event like error, warnings? Do you mind elaborating on your point? thanks

Comment: If a single web request involves 3 INFO log lines and 1 error, you won't be able to view the easily in chronological order if they are written to different log files. If you want to filter a log level out of a single file, just us a standard utility like `grep`.

Comment: @jordanm so what's the best things to do? any recommendation with possible coding demonstration based on what I did above? Do you mind if you can post some update with code as an answer? thanks

Comment: @jordanm I updated my post the app running session from python console which is not logged. how can I make a log of those? Do you share some ideas? thansk

Answer (score -1, accepted):

While I agree with @Jordanm in the comments that I do not understand the reasoning behind wanting to do this,  You can open multiple loggers that each go to different files.

```
import logging

errorlog = logging.getLogger("ErrorLog")
errorlog.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
handler = logging.FileHandler('ProgramErrorLog')
errorlog.addHandler(handler)

warninglog = logging.getLogger("WarningLog")
errorlog.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
handler = logging.FileHandler('ProgramWarningLog')
warninglog.addHandler(handler)

errorlog.error(f'this is an error')
warninglog.warning(f'this is a warning')
```

Send a message to whichever file by choosing which logger you use to send the message

You are using a `StreamHandler` object that you do not specify a destination for.  In order to send your log to a file , you need to use a `FileHandler` object with your desired filename.

replace these two lines of code:

`stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler()`

`log.addHandler(stream_handler)`

with something more like these lines from my example:

```
handler = logging.FileHandler('ProgramErrorLog')
errorlog.addHandler(handler)
```

Comment: let's say your web application is running, how do you handle the event like what's happening in your terminal while you are running your app? Can you update your answer if is possible?

Comment: I updated my post with app session info from python console, which I can't make a log for that. how your output is going to handle that? any thought?

Comment: @beyond_inifinity You are explicitly configuring logs to go to stderr with `log.addHandler(stream_handler)`

Comment: @Alan Hoover that was my thought and coding attempt, but I am open to hear your suggestion what else can be done better for that. seems your answer is not going to address what I concern. I think something more can be done in your attempt. what do you think?

Comment: @jordanm nailed it.  You are sending your log to stderr instead of to a file.

Comment: @Alan Hoover do you have update on your posted answer? you said `nailed it` above comment, what updated you would make on posted answer? honestly, I didn't down vote your answer, as soon as your answer is updated, I am gonna accept it. thanks

Comment: @beyond_inifinity you are sending your log to stderr instead of to your desired file in the line of code that jordanm pointed out in the above comment.

Comment: @AlanHoover I see, what I supposed to do then? clearly your posted answer is not what I expected for. I am curious if you might update your answer before I verify if it does what I need. thanks Alan